# Determine the asp.net core application port

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

For several days I have been searching the Internet for information on what port my asp.net core webapi2 application got up on. I need to use the information in startup.cs

I used the IServerAddressesFeature interface which returns an address to me, but I have trouble when I run the program from VS as an IIS host.

What would you advise to get the correct address also for the IIS host?

Comment: What about using `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress` or `Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress`.

Comment: The best solution would be to have an app setting in the config file that contains this information. If you are not auto scaling etc